# how to remove backslash added json.stringify

Tags: json, replace, stringify

i'am currently working on a object to string conversion and upon reading i need to use json.stringify. I have successfully converted it, however when i try to input a backslash on my javascript object the conversion adds another backslash.

**Scenario:**

on my object variable i used "**\r\n**" after using the json.stringify the result was "\r\n" which should be only "\n" as i used the .replace function

```
                    var str = JSON.stringify(item.NotesContent);
                var exp1 = str.replace(/\r\n/g, "\\\\n");
                console.log("your new string is    : " + exp1);
```

**Result**

[image]

any inputs for this?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the extra backslash? Removing it would produce invalid JSON, which would fail to parse with any other library.

Comment: i need to remove it as i only need to get the string variable for it and i wont be using it to parse to other library